# How round-tripping works in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

From my vague understanding, round-tripping is a process involving conversion between two different API group versions. When converting from a GV (e.g., apps/v1beta1) to another GV (e.g., apps/v1beta2), the first GV will always be converted to internal version first before being converted to intended GV.

I am not sure whether my understanding is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is fairly correct.

The version is a *representation* of the internal data stored in etcd. Kubernetes knows how to manage the data and represent it, and the clients must know how to interact with the versioned interfaces.

The round-trip test primarily ensures that internal objects can be deep-copied, converted, marshaled, and un-marshaled without loss of data. This is really important to be reliable, lest some data is altered along the way and we write an object to the database twice.

Basically, the following must result in identical data:

```
  internal -> external -> json/protobuf -> external -> internal
```

Multiple versions of API objects must be round-trippable for a given Kubernetes release according to Rule #2 of the [Kubernetes Deprecation Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-policy/):

> For example, an object can be written as v1 and then read back as v2 and converted to v1, and the resulting v1 resource will be identical to the original. The representation in v2 might be different from v1, but the system knows how to convert between them in both directions. Additionally, any new field added in v2 must be able to round-trip to v1 and back, which means v1 might have to add an equivalent field or represent it as an annotation.